# Get all folders in a given directory with Groovy script (using Extended choice parameter in Jenkins)

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-groovy, extended-choice-parameter

Im using Extended Choice Parameter in Jenkins.
I want to add a drop down parameter in the job and display all folder names within the given directory using a groovy script

how can i do that ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following groovy script in the extended choice parameter to list all folders under a given folder (You will probably require an admin approval to run this script):

```
import groovy.io.FileType

def list = []

def dir = new File("/var/lib/jenkins/workspace")
dir.eachFileRecurse (FileType.DIRECTORIES) { file ->
   list << file
}
return list
```

However, an easier option will be to use the [Filesystem List Parameter Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/filesystem-list-parameter-plugin/).
The plugin lists file, directory or symlink names of a defined directory and exposes them as selection options for the parameter.
It also supports include/exclude patterns and execution on different nodes .

Comment: Hi Noam, Is it possible to list files under more than one folder using the 'Filesystem List Parameter plugin'? Ex: List all text files under two child folders under a parent folder.

Comment: I don't think the plugin currently supports multiple folder conditions. It supports only one include pattern and one exclude pattern.